# Setting up ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  permit_params :name, :content, :price, :image


  show do 
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :content
      row :price
      rpw :image 
    end 
  end


  form :html => {:enctype => "multipart/form-data} do
    f.inputs do 
      f.input :name
      f.input :content
      f.input :price
      f.input :image
    end
  end
end
```

Now I'm working with ActiveAdmin. What I cannot understand is the difference between "show..do" and "form...do". I would like you explain how they are different and why do I need to write both.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is for showing the record the other to edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer, Paulo. I got it.